# Applying vector in grouped data within function using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, forecasting

Trying to use forecast with grouped_by in r. If I donated use the function, and just specify the vector to be used it not a problem, but if I set the vector in the function it return NA:s.

Any suggestions?

```
fun <- function(data, VECTOR) {
  a <- data %>% 
    group_by(company_id) %>% 
    mutate(count = n()) %>% 
    filter(count > 2) %>%
    arrange(company_id, date) %>%
    do(data.frame(forecast = forecast::forecast(.$VECTOR, h = 2)))
  return(a)
}

fun(data = test, VECTOR = oms)
```

data:

```
 company_id STMT_TO_DT NET_SALES
      <chr>     <date>     <dbl>
1  55600727 2011-12-01   1951000
2  55600727 2012-12-01   1934000
3  55600727 2013-12-01   1902000
4  55600727 2014-12-01   1951000
5  55600727 2015-12-01   1930000
6  55600784 2012-06-01       413
7  55600784 2013-06-01       476
8  55600784 2014-06-01       301
9  55600784 2015-06-01       385
10 55600784 2016-06-01      1867
```

As stated before, if no function is used:

```
a <- data %>% 
group_by(company_id) %>% 
mutate(count = n()) %>% 
filter(count > 2) %>%
arrange(company_id, STMT_TO_DT) %>%
do(data.frame(forecast = forecast::forecast(.$NET_SALES, h = 2)))`
```

Following results was obtained:

```
company_id forecast.Point.Forecast forecast.Lo.80 forecast.Hi.80 forecast.Lo.95 forecast.Hi.95
      <chr>                   <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 55600727                 1936302   1.906994e+06    1965610.447       1891478.7440    1981125.371
2 55600727                 1936302   1.905888e+06    1966715.952   1889788.0197    1982816.095
3 55600784                     791   9.511396e+01       1486.886      -273.2659       1855.266
4 55600784                     854   1.581140e+02       1549.886      -210.2659       1918.266`
```

Comment: If the `VECTOR` is not a column in your dataset, you may not need `.$VECTOR`.  Also, in a function, it is useful to have `[` instead of `$`

Comment: already tried that. If one excludes .$VECTOR the forecasting will be done on the entire vector and not the grouped vector.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output